# How to get Tag and check the object in update?

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I want to delete the sprite or b2body.  After that i am going to check if the object is available or not.

I have the following coding:

I have removed the object using the tag:

```
 this->removeChildByTag(100,true)      //this is not in update function
```

In update function:

```
 if(node->getTag()==100)
 {
      CCLog("node is available");
 }
```

Here i got issue "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x84)" in node->getTag() line.

Is there any wrong on this code?

Is any alternate way to handle to check the node or object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that previously, you called something like:

```
addChild(node);
```

This added the node to the container (your CCScene derived class).  When you called

```
this->removeChildByTag(100,true);
```

the "node" instance was destroyed.

A better check would be something like:

```
CCSprite* pNode = (CCSprite*)getChildByTag(100);
if(pNode == NULL)
{   // This node is available
    // Do something here...
}
```